# Vue js | How to access a field :type attribute in script tags

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

```html
<div class="row">
  <ValidationProvider v-slot="{errors, valid}" rules="required" class="col-md-6">
    <b-field :label="$t('admin_global_username')" :type="{'is-success':valid, 'is-danger': errors[0]}" :message="errors && $t(errors[0])">
      <b-input v-model="employeeModal.modalData.username" type="text" />
    </b-field>
  </ValidationProvider>
</div>
```

I am using Vee-validate and i want this : İf b-field :type in is-danger mode. user can't go other page. how can i know what is the type in script tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to `<b-field>`, and check its `type` prop directly in the form's `submit`-event handler:

```html
<b-field ref="myField" />
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    submit() {
      if (this.$refs.myField.type === 'is-danger') {
        alert('you shall not pass!')
      } else {
        console.log('submitting')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VwpMPqx?editors=1010)

Comment: oh yes. i just need handle submit in my button @click="handleSubmit(method)". Vee validate already do that for me. Thank u